# useMediaQuery typescript error (condition will always return true since the function is always defined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use `useMediaQuery` in my react app for my responsive js media queries. I'm using typescript version 4.0.3.

The code is as follows:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useMediaQuery = (query: string) => {
    const [match, setMatch] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const updateMatch = () => setMatch(window.matchMedia(query).matches)

        updateMatch()
        if (window.matchMedia(query).addEventListener) {
            window.matchMedia(query).addEventListener('change', updateMatch)
        } else {
            window.matchMedia(query).addListener(updateMatch)
        }
        return () => {
            if (window.matchMedia(query).removeEventListener) {
                window.matchMedia(query).removeEventListener('change', updateMatch)
            } else {
                window.matchMedia(query).removeListener(updateMatch)
            }
        }
    }, [query])

    return match
}

export default useMediaQuery
```

**The error message I'm getting is:**

`This condition will always return true since the function is always defined. Did you mean to call it instead?  TS2774`

```
updateMatch()
  if (window.matchMedia(query).addEventListener) {
       ^
```

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this code to get it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just don`t need this condition. On my env I have error

```
deprecated MediaQueryList.removeListener
```

so you will have another issue when fix current

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.matchMedia(query).addEventListener) {...}
```

This will always return the function reference. So it will always execute the if block. That's why typescript is throwing error. So instead of using if/else, you could directly call the methods.

```
window.matchMedia(query).addEventListener('change', updateMatch)
window.matchMedia(query).addListener(updateMatch)
```

Comment: Ive removed the if and else statements, and the one in the return. Im now getting a host of other errors:

Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Any ideas?